# How can login to other TRU64 from Linux?

Tags: unix, remote-access, x-windows, x-server, hp-ux

i want to connect to a TRU64 machine from Linux system same as:

> "login a client to a windows network how can login from all machine from on that network"

now i can connect to a TRU64 machine with VNC but that not my aim, i want connect directly to x-server from a TRU64 machine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, TRU64 hosts often have IP, why don't you `ssh` from one host to another ?

Comment: @Archemar, I want to run a graphical application on TRU64 in X-Wndows system